# Kibana stops showing data after a while. Logs too big?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I'm running PALallax, which is a custom version of Kibana / ElasticSearch for Palo Alto firewalls. I have it installed on CentOS 7 with more than enough resources (4 processors, 16GB of RAM). It works fine - however, almost every single day, half way through, Kibana will stop showing results and end up with the dreaded "no results found". I know it works, though. The log file continues to grow (which is big, by the way - about 11GB half way through the day). No matter what I do, I can't get any information to display until I delete the log and indices files on the server and reboot - then it starts working again.

I've looked through logs all around the system and can't figure out what is going on. I'm not an Linux expert, so unfortunately I've run out of ideas and have nothing else to try. I've spent countless days googling different things and haven't been able to isolate any specific problem in the logs.

Any suggestions on where to look? Are my logs too big? I can see that I'm not running out of RAM while this is happening. I always have it set for 'last hour' worth of data, set to auto-refresh every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Monitor the free disk space and set up automatic deletion of old indices to avoid running out of disk space.